# Get Android Keyboard Height

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-input-method

I am trying to get android keyboard Height with following code

```
parentLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    parentLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                    int screenHeight = parentLayout.getRootView().getHeight();
                    int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom);

                    previousHeightDiffrence = heightDifference;
                    if (heightDifference > 100) {
                        isKeyBoardVisible = true;
                        changeKeyboardHeight(heightDifference);


                    } else {
                        if(emojiKeyboard.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){
                            emojiKeyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        isKeyBoardVisible = false;
                    }

                }
            });
```

and that works well with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` but that results my activity screen to move upward when default keyboard shows up.
All I need is to get keyboard height and show my custom keyboard **under** default keyboard, according to me that's only possible with`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="AdjustNothing"`.
And if set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` then I can't get keyboard height.
I need alternative solution for my problem.
Advance Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for calc keyboard height:

```
public static int getKeyboardHeight() {
 // viewMain <-- findViewById( android.R.id.content).getRootView();

 if( viewMain != null)  iSoftkeyboardHeight = viewMain.getHeight();

 int y = iSoftkeyboardHeight - 2;
 int x = 10;
 int counter = 0;
 int height = y;
 int iSoftkeyboardHeightNow = 0;
 Instrumentation instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
 while( true) {
    final MotionEvent m = MotionEvent.obtain(  SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
    final MotionEvent m1 = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,   x, y, 0);
    boolean ePointerOnSoftkeyboard = false;

    try {
        instrumentation.sendPointerSync(m);
        instrumentation.sendPointerSync(m1);
      }
     catch (SecurityException e) {
         ePointerOnSoftkeyboard = true;
      }
    if( !ePointerOnSoftkeyboard) {
        if( y == height) {
            if( counter++ < 100) {
                Thread.yield();
                continue;
              }
          }
         else
          if( y > 0)
            iSoftkeyboardHeightNow = iSoftkeyboardHeight - y;
        break;
      }
    y--;
    m.recycle();
    m1.recycle();
  }
 if( iSoftkeyboardHeightNow > 0)  iSoftkeyboardHeight = iSoftkeyboardHeightNow;
  else iSoftkeyboardHeight = 0;
 return iSoftkeyboardHeight;
```

}

Comment: It is always giving 0 for keyboard height.!

Comment: I am giving parent layout of activity as viewMain.

Answer (score 0):

```
rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        parent.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        int screenHeight = parent.getRootView().getHeight();
        int heightDifference = screenHeight - (r.bottom - r.top);
        Log.d("Keyboard Size", "Size: " + heightDifference);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this code -

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText editText) {
    if (null != editText) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) editText.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide keyboard, I want to get size of keyboard.